# How to overwrite the css properties inherited by parent tag in child tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have  a bootstrap element card and I have divided that card body into 3 parts(divs). Now in the last div I want the area to be covered with background -color. But I am unable to do it because of card-body class which has inbuilt feature of padding:1.25rem;
Code is as follows.

```
<div class="card col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
      <div class="card-body  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="display:flex">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8" style="color:#f93d3d;"><h5>This is some text within a card body.</h5> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">&euro;7890 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" style="background-color:#3c3c3c"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: your last div is empty so background color can't set

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="card col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
      <div class="card-body  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  col-lg-12 col-xl-12" style="display:flex">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8" style="color:#f93d3d;"><h5>This is some text within a card body.</h5> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">&euro;7890 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" style="background-color:#3c3c3c;color:#fff;">test</div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

look this